# Easy way to inter splice columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Suppose I have two data.frames

DataFrame 1:

```
 Subject    metric_1a   metric_1b   metric_1c
    a        933.9       884.3      474.5
    b        993.3       557.4      484.2
    c        822.4       575.5      848.2
```

DataFrame 2:

```
 Subject    metric_2a   metric_2b   metric_2c
    a        933.9       884.3        474.5
    b        993.3       557.4        484.2
    c        822.4       575.5        848.2
```

and I want to produce:

```
  Subject    metric_1a   metric_2a   metric_1b  metric_2b  metrics_1c  metric_2c 
     a         933.9       933.9       884.3       884.3      474.5       474.5
     b         993.3       993.3       557.4       557.4      484.2       484.2
     c         822.4       822.4       575.5       575.5      848.2       848.2
```

How can I easily do this?

Comment: Just `merge()` your data and then use indexing `[,]` to put the columns in whatever order you want. In most cases order shouldn't be that important; is there something i'm missing?

Comment: No -- that is far less clunky than my solution. Thank you. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use cbind in a similar fashion

```
df1 <- data.frame(subject = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                  metric_1a = c(123, 456, 789), 
                  metric_1b = c(123, 456, 789), 
                  metric_1c = c(123, 456, 789))

df2 <- data.frame(subject = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  metric_2a = c(123, 456, 789),
                  metric_2b = c(123, 456, 789),
                  metric_2c = c(123, 456, 789))

cbind(df1[1], df1[2], df2[2], df1[3], df2[3], df1[4], df2[4])
```